# Convert Snort string to Python timestamp

Tags: python, snort

I'm using Snort, which generates timestamps in MM-DD/time format, such as:

```
06/18-19:31:05.688344
```

I want to convert this to a Python timestamp, including the current year. What's the most pythonic way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/datetime.html) module's `strptime` function.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(str(datetime.datetime.now().year) +
... '/' + '06/18-19:31:05.688344', '%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S.%f')
datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 18, 19, 31, 5, 688344)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out snorts configuration. In the output section you can setup "seconds" as an output field. This is the timestamp in unix format which is better to work with. If u still need to convert it :

```
datetime.utcfromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```